# cannot get Nodejs express mongoose working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I issue localhost:8000/api/customers I am getting empty array even though I inserted data in mongodb. I tested the route localhost:8000/api/customers without connecting to mongodb and it displays a static text.However, when connecting to Mongodb it returns empty array. here is the code

```
var express = require('express'),
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection err'));
db.once('open', function callback(){console.log('connected to db')});
var Customer = require('./Customers/models/customerModel');
var app = express(),
port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
customerRouter = express.Router();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
customerRouter.route('/Customers')
  .post(function(req, res){
    var customer = new Customer(req.body);
    console.log(customer);
    res.send(customer);
  })
  .get(function(req,res){
    Customer.find(function(err,customers){
        if(err)
            res.status(500).send(err);
        else {
            res.json(customers);
            console.log(customers);
        }
    });
  });
app.use('/api', customerRouter);
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Welcome to my API')
});
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Running on port ' + port);
});
```

and the customerModel.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var customerModel = new Schema({
    name: {type: String},
    contact: {type: String},
    date_register: {type: String},
    main_tel: {type: String},
    tel_1: {type: String},
    tel_2: {type: String},
    tel_3: {type: String},
    address: {type: String},
    email: {type: String}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Customer', customerModel);
```

I am using gulp task runner on port 8000

Comment: Hi Ryan just tried it no results the same thing

Comment: Do you see `connected to db`?

Comment: Aleix yes i do. Just doing fresh install on ubuntu 14.04 will post back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using `Customer.find` properly. Check out the docs:

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

There are supposed to be two arguments for `find()`. The first argument is the criteria for the find method (the "WHERE" condition if you will), the second argument is the callback. Update your code from this:

```
Customer.find(function(err,customers){ ...
```

to this:

```
Customer.find({}, function(err,customers){ ...
```

Passing an empty object means "give me everything". If you later wanted to find all customers with the first name "John", you would do something like this:

```
Customer.find({firstName: "John"}, function(err,customers){ ...
```

Comment: This is the code now     .get(function(req,res){
        Customer.find({},function(err,customers){
            if(err)
                res.status(500).send(err);
            else {
                res.json(customers);
                console.log(customers);
            }
        });
    }); calling  http://localhost:8000/api/customers  --- still empty

Comment: this is how I am calling the db collection in mongodb > db.Customer.find() and I get the records but not via api

Comment: Try connecting to the db on the default port: `mongodb://localhost:27017/test`

Comment: no luck here is the log from gulp - Running on port 8000
connected to db
[]

Comment: if you have a working sample similar to the above, I would actually try it on my ubuntu 16.04

Comment: root@ubuntu:~# lsof -i | grep mongo
mongod    35601 mongodb    6u  IPv4  78252      0t0  TCP localhost:27017 (LISTEN)
mongod    35601 mongodb   22u  IPv4  97400      0t0  TCP localhost:27017->localhost:57706 (ESTABLISHED) --- I get mongo text in red in mongod above.... does it mean anything?

Comment: I dropped the collection Customer, changed test --> test123 db and tried POST some json data, I get status 200 OK, and I can see _id in the response using Postman, Cannot see the db test123 in Mongodb though weird. Any idea guys?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I resolved it, I missed out the customer.save(cb(err)) in the POST. Now GET is working. thank you all